# Set Uncheck The Folium Basemap layers as default value

Tags: python, streamlit, folium

I created a folium map on streamlit.
I added several basemap with this code:

```
basemaps['Google Maps'].add_to(map)
basemaps['Google Satellite Hybrid'].add_to(map)
basemaps['Google Terrain'].add_to(map)
basemaps['Esri Satellite'].add_to(map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)
```

My expectation is the default value is uncheck. Unfortunately on folium LayerControl all basemaps are checked like this:

[image: all basemaps are checked]

Any solution to make the default value is unchecked?

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to add these basemaps as different mapstyles. So the solution should be, that the styles are added as radiobuttons, not checkboxes?

Would look somthing like this:

```
import folium


#### define map with selectable styles

geo_start = [52.5172, 13.3024]
dmap = folium.Map(location=geo_start,
                  zoom_start=8,
                  tiles='OpenStreetMap'
                  )


mapstyle_2 = folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(tiles='CartoDB dark_matter',
                                            name='dark',
                                            overlay=False,
                                            control=True,
                                            show=True,
                                            )
mapstyle_2.add_to(dmap)


# the layercontrol itself
lc = folium.map.LayerControl(collapsed=False)
lc.add_to(dmap)

dmap
```